# Svn Git Migration : How to migrate selected projects from two different branches in svn to GIT with commit history

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I have two branches in SVN.

My requirement is to migrate two projects from branch1 and one project from branch2 in svn to GIT with commit history.

Need inputs on how to achieve this.

Comment: The best advice is, don't.  In git, a repo should contain a single project. You can always create another repo to list the project repos as submodules, if you really need an integrated view of all the projects' source; but even that is something I avoid.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably best not to do it. It sounds like a bad idea to stuff mutliple projects into one repository.

If you still want to do it, I'd recommmend using the KDE `svn2git`. (Be aware to use the right one, nirvdrum `svn2git` e. g. is not what I'm talking about) It will be pretty easy to get the rules setup to produce the result you want to have.